# Calling a process from Office add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-addins

I have an shared office add-in that uses a separate process to delete files using the following code:

```
string currentDir = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentDir);
Process.Start(Path.Combine(currentDir, "process.exe"), "/d \"" + file + "\"");
```

This seems to randomly be unable to find the process even though it is in the same directory as the add-in.
I would like to avoid having to add the directory to the PATH variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: By randomly...do you mean sometimes `Process.Start` works or that it never works?

Comment: yes, sometimes it works then sometimes it throws an error and cant find the exe

Comment: Try using [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I would like to avoid having to add the directory to the PATH variable.

That will not help, Process.Start must be provided the fully-qualified path.

I would recommend updating the installer to write the install directory into the registry.  Make sure to grant everyone read access on the key/value.  Using assembly.Location and/or AppDomain.CurrentDirectory can be very problematic from within another application.  Just avoid it and use a well-known value storage.

Comment: You can call process in a PATH folder without using the fully-qualified path!